# View code inside procedure in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I have a procedure in SQL developer and I want to view what is written inside that procedure..how should I do it?

I am unable to see the code written inside the procedure but I am able to see the procedure structure when I run the query desc schema name.procedure name

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `connections` tab which is in the left side of sql developer.

Click the `+` icon near schema name then `+` near procedure as shown in the pic.Under that you will have all the existing procedure. You can click any of it to view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Developer**

Browse to the connection name in the connections tab, expand the required object and just click, it will open the code in new tab.

**ALL|USER|DBA_SOURCE view**

Alternatively, you could query the `DBA_SOURCE` view:

```
SELECT text
FROM user_source
WHERE owner='<owner_name>'
AND name   ='<procedure_name>'
AND type   ='PROCEDURE';
```

make sure you put the owner_name and procedure_name in **UPPER** case, or in the exact case if you created using double-quotation marks.